# +2 Reputation is Not Shown

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, self-answer

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8bdd86e916.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8bdd86e916.png)

As seen in the above image, in my Stack Overflow account, +2 reputation is not showing in "Exact Different between "Content-Provider" and "SQLite Database"" question, but there should be +2 reputation highlighted.

I dont know why +2 reputation is not showing up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't get +2 for accepting your own answer.

Comment: ...Oh really ?? i dont know, i see it for the first time

Comment: @roe..It is not embarrassing for me...but for its for you..becoz i am newbie since last month..i know that accepting our self's answer, we are not eligible to get +2..but i see it above...it was my mistake that i understood it as "bug" so i considered to post for the future help to SO

Comment: @Paresh You got a +2 for accepting [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325197/location-of-sqlite-database-when-application-is-executed-on-real-device/3325434#3325434), as you can read from the report: "Acc +2 [Location of SQLite Database when application is executed on real device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325197/location-of-sqlite-database-when-application-is-executed-on-real-device)", not [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350408/exact-difference-between-content-provider-and-sqlite-database/3362595#3362595).

Comment: What about +15 for providing the accepted answer?!

Comment: @w3d, you get 0 total rep for accepting your own answer to your own question. (You still get rep from question and answer upvotes, however.)